# How can I stop autoformatting of comments in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, comments

I like to indent my comments. Visual Studio 2010 removes the indenting format I make. How can I prevent that from happening?

Here is an example of what I am talking about. Before I code, I comment. It helps me to keep the picture of where I want to go when things get convoluted. So if I am going to code a lab coat I will write the comments for that part like this:

```
//Make lab coat
    //Add pockets
        //Add pen to top pocket
    //Add buttons
    //Add Name Tag
        //Put Name On Name Tag
```

And then I would go back in and fill in the code for the commented section. This is just an example of formatting, lets not get into the semantics of lab coat implementation.

However, in Visual Studio 2010, if I start adding some code, the auto-formatter will remove all of the indentation for the comments. I tried looking at the editor options but couldn't figure out if the setting existed for this case.

### How can I prevent Visual Studio 2010 from removing these indentations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this workaround, but I was hoping for a more legit method for accomplishing this.

```
//Build lab coat
{
    //Add Pockets
    {
        //Add pen to top pocket

    }
    //Add Buttons
    {

    }
    //Add Name Tag
    {
        //Add name to name tag
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding your indentation after the double forward slashes?